# VS Code autocomplete not working for CSS properties in GlobalStyles used in other styled components

Tags: visual-studio-code, styled-components

I'm currently working on a Project where I defined Global Styles in a different file and declared styling in another file. Still, somehow the custom properties defined in GlobalStyles don't get autocomplete.

I am using, [VScode Styled component](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components) extension

// GlobalStyles.tsx

```
import React from 'react';

import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';
import { COLORS } from '../constants';

const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`
    /* CSS Reset */
      :root {
    /* Primary */
    --color-primary-10: hsl(25, 35%, 93%);
}
`;
```

// Search.tsx

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Wrapper = styled.section`
  /* VS Code doesn't autocomplete  */
  color: var(--)
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this extension in your vscode, It provides Intellisense for both linked and embedded style sheets.

```
Id: ecmel.vscode-html-css
Description: CSS Intellisense for HTML
Version: 1.13.1
Publisher: ecmel
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-html-css
```